# OS Vulnerabilities examples

Tags: linux, security, operating-system

I am trying to learn about OS security. I need to find a good tutorial with some examples about vulnerabilities and scripts concerning OS vulnerabilities. For example, I need someone to guide me on how to perform some attacks on a Linux virtual machine, and tutorials on how to create attacks on such VMs if possible.

Comment: @you can hire people to do that :)

Comment: this should go to http://security.stackexchange.com, but this question will be closed there almost for sure.

Comment: @BlunT I don't want to hire people, I want to learn.

Comment: @MichałŠrajer why would it be closed?

Comment: @NicolasElKhoury because InfoSec folks dislike "how do I hack X"-kind of questions, but you can try if you want.

Comment: I love downvoting and closing questions like this.

Comment: @MichałŠrajer [security.se] accepts black hat questions. But they still have to be suitable for Stack Exchange. This question is far too broad. But it can be reasonably answered by searching such tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

if you kindly ask for active linux [0days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing)), then you will not find the answer that easy. Such information const load of money.

Perhaps you should first get a good book on information security to understand basic concepts like buffer overflow, integer overflow shell code and stuff like that. Once you understand basics, you can for example analyze [debian security patches](https://www.debian.org/security/).

Answer (score 0):

Here are few recommendations

Try metasploit and nessuss vulnerability scanner to scan a system for vulnerability to have real visibility of vulnerabilities. One of such vulnerability is stack overflow/buffer overflow. many people exploited this to launch attack. You can find many attacks and vulnerability stuff from research community. Many easy to understand books are also available such as "Linux hackig exposed"
Search in youtube for how to hack system.

Best of luck for your new exciting journey